# In Craft 2, check if plugin is available for Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

I'm currently running a Craft 2 site.

I thought there was a quick place to check my plugins to tell if they are ready for 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click the updates link in the footer and you should see this at the bottom of the page.

[image]